# How can I get the API Name of a related EntityDefinition?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-metadata, describes

I'm trying to use `Custom Metadata Types` to specify some relationships between objects. So I started out by creating my `Custom Metadata Type` and adding a `Metadata Relationship` to an `Entity Definition`.

In implementing this approach, I ran into an interesting surprise. When I tried to get an object's describe based on `DeveloperName`, it didn't give me any data. If I have an object whose API Name is `My_Object__c`, the `DeveloperName` field contains `My_Object`.

```
MyMetadata__mdt mapping = [
    SELECT SObjectType__c, SObjectType__r.DeveloperName
    FROM MyMetadata__mdt LIMIT 1
];
system.debug(mapping.SObjectType__c); // yields 01I00000000xxxx
system.debug(mapping.SObjectType__r.DeveloperName); // yields My_Object
SObjectType s = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(mapping.SObjectType__r.DeveloperName);
```

Is there no way to get it to return the API Name in a way I can pass directly to describe methods? The same problem applies when I try to query a related `Field Definition` as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both the [`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) and [`FieldDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) objects have a field called `QualifiedApiName` that does what I am looking for:

```
MyMetadata__mdt mapping = [
    SELECT SObjectType__r.QualifiedApiName
    FROM MyMetadata__mdt LIMIT 1
];
system.debug(mapping.SObjectType__r.QualifiedApiName); // yields My_Object__c
SObjectType s = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(mapping.SObjectType__r.QualifiedApiName);
```

When using this field, I can successfully retrieve describes in a dynamic manner.